# Scrolling on web pages

Tags: user-interface, user-experience

"People don't like to scroll on web pages." Does this statement hold any water? This is client's preference but is there anyway to educate him that scrolling is part of using the browser and nothing wrong with it.

Or am I wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ask the client what his favourite web sites are. I'd defy him to have any that don't scroll in there (unless he last went on the web in y2k).

Comment: I think there's good value in this methodology.  Could unlock an "Aha!" moment.

Answer (score 0):

Stackoverflow.com isn't for discussion, however, I can give you some brief info on the subject.  Scrolling is a tedias task.  Horizontal scrolling is a HUGE NO NO.  This is because people dislike having to grab the bar because most people don't have a horizontal scroller on their mouse.  Vertical scrolling is ok but, if you can, for simple pages (such as logins, about pages, etc.) make them as short as possible to prevent scrolling.

People may just be lazy but, you can't change the people, you have to adapt your resources for them.

Oh, welcome to Stackoverflow.com by the way :)

Comment: http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2011/03/35-awesome-and-beautiful-examples-of-horizontal-scrolling-websites.html - :P

Comment: In the form of a more general situation =P  This is discussing something that will always be an exception.  Innovation :)

Answer (score 0):

I feel that it depends on the purpose of your website.  An informational website could very well require scrolling; while a web application it kind of depends.  Think of Google Mail (no scrolling) or Google Images (scrolling).

"It depends" <-- typical programming answer, right?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything wrong in scrolling on the web pages..Maybe you can show him various web pages as example..Maybe he would be convinced if he sees a no. of web pages using scroll bars..

Answer (score 0):

[Web users spend 80% of their time looking at information above the page fold. Although users do scroll, they allocate only 20% of their attention below the fold.](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/scrolling-attention.html)

There's definitely an advantage in putting your important stuff above the fold. But the context is important, web apps generally model non-scrolling Desktop apps, like others have said.